# Updating Google Analytics (UA) export tables in BigQuery - how to unnest?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics

I want to update the existing GA (universal analytics) table that I exported to BigQuery. What I want to do is modifying the existing **hits.eventInfo.eventLabel** field that contains **'abc'** into **'xyz'**. I wrote this script, but it's giving me the "*Cannot access field eventInfo on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<hitNumber INT64, time INT64, hour INT64, ...>> at [10:12]*” error.

```
UPDATE `myProject.ga_sessions_20220403`
SET hits = ARRAY(
  SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE (
    (SELECT AS STRUCT *
      REPLACE ('null' AS eventLabel)
      FROM UNNEST([eventInfo])
    ) AS eventInfo)
  FROM UNNEST(hits)
  )
WHERE hits.eventInfo.eventLabel = 'abc'
```

What am I doing wrong, and how do I get this to work?

Also, how does the query change if I want to update multiple tables (ie. multiple dates) with the same criteria? and what if I want to add another WHERE clause that accesses the page RECORD (eg. **hits.eventInfo.eventLabel = ‘abc’** AND **hits.page.pagePath = ‘12345’**)?

Answer (score 0):

You should keep the exact same structure of hits after update.
In the schema, hits is an array of struct with many fields.
This struct also contains eventInfo, which is another struct.

Firstly, since hits is an array, you can't access hits.eventInfo in the where statement. If you want to filter hits that contain eventInfo.eventLabel "abc" and pagePath '12345', you can use this where condition:

```
where exists (select 1 from unnest(hits) as hit where hit.eventInfo.eventLabel = 'abc' AND hit.page.pagePath = '12345')
```

Secondly, since eventInfo is not an array, you don't need to unnest it, you can just directly access its elements.

So you can see all the code here:

```
update `myProject.ga_sessions_20220403`
set hits =  
  ARRAY(
  (
      SELECT AS STRUCT 
      * REPLACE 
      (
        case when eventInfo is not null 
        then
          (
            select as struct eventInfo.* replace 
            (
              CASE 
                WHEN eventInfo.eventLabel = 'abc' THEN 'null'
                ELSE eventInfo.eventLabel
              END as eventLabel
            )
          )
        end as eventInfo
      )
  FROM UNNEST(hits) as hit
  ))
WHERE exists (select 1 from unnest(hits) as hit where hit.eventInfo.eventLabel = 'abc' AND hit.page.pagePath = '12345')
```

Besides all the code above, I don't recommend updating the original data, so I'd create another table using a select statement instead of updating the original table, in case you want to access original data in the future.

Comment: I believe **WHERE EXISTS** is more preferred in this case. ;o).   
**WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits) hit WHERE hit.eventInfo.eventLabel = 'abc' AND hit.page.pagePath = '12345')**

Comment: And for **UNNEST([eventInfo])**, @paul 's approach is more general because it doesn't require you to list all the fields in **eventInfo** again.

Comment: You're definitely right about where exists, I'm editing the post.
For eventInfo, unnest is a bad approach since it duplicates the number of rows. However, we still can use select as struct. 
In addition, I realized that I'm creating an eventInfo even though eventInfo is null. So I also fixed it in the new code.